# Projection of a real analytic manifold onto subspace is union of real analytic submanifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a compact connected real analytic submanifold of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}$ and denote by $\pi : \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the projection onto the first $n$ coordinates.

Is it possible to show (or is it already known) that $\pi(M)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the union of finitely many real analytic manifolds? Are there any references of this topic?

Best,
Hugo

Comment: That is obviously false. Look at the projection of a sphere. Check Tarski–Seidenberg theorem, but beware that it does not hold for semianalytic sets.

Comment: http://library.msri.org/books/Book39/files/bierstone.pdf